# How to write to the console before a function panics?

Tags: go

In C you can use the function `write()` from the `unistd.h` library.
`write()` is faster than `printf()`, and allows you to write to the standard output (or a file) before a Segfault breaks your code.

When debugging, I wish to write to the standard output before my Go code panics.  In general, how do I do that?

I have the following code (to find the shortest word in a string of words) which is panicking and I want to isolate where, by inserting write methods.

```
func FindShort(s string) int {
  i := 0
  j := 0
  min := math.MaxInt32
  for true {
    for s[i] == ' ' {
      i++
      j++
    }
    for s[j] != ' ' && j < len(s) {
      j++
    }
    if j > i && (j - i) < min {
      min = j - i
    }
    i = j
    if j == len(s) {
      break
    }
  }
  return min
}
```

Comment: The `fmt` Print functions are not buffered like C's `printf` is. Can you provide some more context or code for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess you could recover from the panic at the root level and flush the buffer before exiting?

Comment: I think it also depends on what you want to write to std output. What do you wish to write ?

Comment: You can't recover panics in other goroutines. You can can either recover your own goroutine's panics, which mean you can do whatever you want, or you have the let the program crash as intended.

Comment: @TimCooper I have added some code.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a defered function that calls the recover function, the function below will result in "Recovered panic here"

```
defer func() {
    r := recover()
    if r != nil {
        fmt.Println("Recovered", r)
    }
}()

panic("panic here")
```

Comment: Careful. This recovers the panic - and the program will continue - which may not be what the OP was asking for.  A side effect of the above, if used within a function that has return values, the returned values will be given default values e.g. RowCount() int - would return 0 - which may or may not be what you want. If not, then the panic should be re-raised in the defer closure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks all lines if it contains a space, but it isn't checking if the line ends (end of line / end of file / line feed). There is a easier way to check what the shortest word is :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    min := math.MaxInt32
    shortest := math.MaxInt32
    s := strings.Split("this is a test", " ")
    for key, value := range s {
        if len(value) < min {
            min = len(value)
            shortest = key
        }
    }
    fmt.Print(s[shortest])
}
```